# Are there any ways to know whether the element has failed under loading, while knowing only limited properties?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, civil-engineering, concrete, abaqus

I opt to check whether a precast concrete wall (no reinforcements, only concrete) withstand both vertical and lateral loading condition but the only properties I know are the Young's Modulus, density, poisons ratio and the Grade of concrete by which the panel is made.
I have experimental tests' report, but for a completely different panel and it has maximum compressive load applied and  4 point flexural strength of that panel, NO MATERIAL DATA are available for this tested panel.

The panel under consideration is a precast hollow core panel, pure concrete panel, no reinforcements. Applied maximum direct compression load of 300 kN on the panel, maximum flexural capacity of 1N/mm2, that's all the data I was provided with. It is made up of concrete but no data on what grade of concrete it is. This is the test panel. The panel I modelled is under vertical column shortening displacement as a boundary condition, wind load normal to the panel and of Grade 25 concrete.

Can someone help me how I can conclude whether the panel will withstand under my loading conditions and is there are any way to verify my computer model using the available data?
Modeling is done in ABAQUS.

Comment: Please provide whatever data you have for information, we couldn't guess.

Comment: The panel under consideration is a precast hollow core panel, pure concrete panel, no reinforcements. 
Applied maximum direct compression load of 300 kN on the panel, maximum flexural capacity of 1N/mm2, that's all the data I was provided with. It is made up of concrete but no data on what grade of concrete it is. This is the test panel.

The panel I modelled is under vertical column shortening displacement as a boundary condition, wind load normal to the panel and of Grade 25 concrete.

Comment: please put additional information in the text of the question

Answer (score 1):

You have left out the most important data of the concrete - grade 25 concrete (M25), which has a compressive strength ($f_c'$) of, approximately, 3600 psi (or 3625 psi to be close to exact).

I assume you are an engineer, from here you shall be able to determine its elastic (Young's) modulus, maximum tensile strength prior to crack, and the allowable stresses whether it is subjected to the gravity or lateral load.

Note, if only know Young's Modulus ($E_c$), you can estimate $f_c'$ by using the equation such as $E_c = 57000\sqrt{f_c'}$ (Imperial System).

For hollow-core slab without reinforcement, you shall look into the best practice recommendations offered by the manufacturer, on how to position/support the panel, and the position and limits of load applications. In general, watch out for shear and avoid placing the concentrated load on the voided cells, unless the cells are to be grouted solid.

If you have other questions or concerns, please provide a sketch with the type of applied load indicated.

Comment: I am an Engineering UG, the section of the panel (height 2700mm) is 5 circular hollow cores on a rectangular section (100mmx700mm). I wanted to see whether it will withstand vertical displacement, together with lateral load. I got a test results of a different panel section, it has only the direct compressive strength and 4 point flexural strength. I am using ABAQUS for this. The panel I will model is of Grade 25 pure concrete, tested panel's concrete grade is unknown. What parameters should I need to verify or how can I incorporate the test results with the model?

Comment: You should perform calculations using the proposed parameters if your interest is to check the strength of the new panel. If you want to "verify" the failure mode of the test panel (properties unknown), you need to know the panel geometry, load pattern (location and spacing of the test loads), type of test (vertical compressive or horizontal beam test), type of failure (shear, bending, compression) and the maximum load causing the failure. From there, you should be able to back-check the f'c of the test panel. I am still puzzled on what you want to do then.